# Can I inject properties to third-party beans?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Suppose I have classes, which were instantiated not by Spring. For example, they can be instantiated by deserializer or by `JavaFX`.

Can I code these classes in the same way I code Spring beans and inject properties into them later?

Actually, I would like a routine, which would scan class with reflection, find all `@Autowired` annotations in it and inject values from application context?

Will this happen, if I call `applicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("myName", myBean)`? Note, that I would no limit myself with singletons.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Because Spring container would create a proxy object which is then a wrapper of the original and registers with the bean factory. So i doubt if we try to do the container's job whether it would work with actual instance.

Answer (score 0):

If beans are not instantiated by Spring, then you cannot ask Spring to inject dependencies or advise them.

This is a common mistake I see Spring neophytes make.  They call new to instantiate a bean with annotations and can't understand why their dependencies aren't injected.

Spring will handle all the beans you instantiate with the bean factory.  You are on your own with all others created using new.

Comment: Okay, but that's not me, who is `Spring` neophyte, these are `JavaFX` developers, who are Spring neophytes :)

Comment: Whatever.  Spring isn't responsible for beans created outside the factory.  You'd have to write your own code to do it.  JavaFX?  I thought that was dead.  Lots of other UI technologies to choose from.  I'd pick one supported by Spring.

Comment: Why can't I reuse code, which is already present inside Spring?

Comment: Better ask Spring that.

Comment: Is this really true I can't reuse injecting code from Spring?

Comment: BTW, what other libraries like `JavaFX` you know?

Comment: Like JavaFX?  You mean Flash?  Dead as a doornail.

Comment: No, I mean normal desktop library, not web thin client libraries, so `HTML5` is not an answer

Comment: One to a customer.  I'm not a desktop UI person.   It's all web now for me.

Comment: Okay. So what about injecting code inside Spring? Is it really closed?

Comment: I gave my answer.  Either wait for someone else or move on.   I'm done.