# Can I instantiate bean programmatically in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Suppose I have an instance of `Class<?>` and I am already in Spring. Can I instantiate a bean for Spring in this situation?

I want to simulate situation as if I had the following bean definition:

```
@Bean
MyClass myBean() {
   return new MyClass();
}
```

i.e. only call no-arg constructor and autowire dependencies.

Is this possible?

Probably this is somehow related with programmatic creation of bean definitions.

This is modification of the following question: [Can I inject properties to third-party beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346511/can-i-inject-properties-to-third-party-beans)

**UPDATE**

I used

```
bean = getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(klass);
```

and for now it is apparently working.

Is this correct?

Comment: You mean [`Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance())?

Comment: Yes. But it should be a bean, i.e. autowired, common interfaces processed etc.

Comment: You mean [`context.getBean()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-)?

Comment: `context.getBean()` won't work if there is no configured bean yet

Comment: This is very different than what you originally asked. You said you already had an instance. Your update would be creating an entirely new instance.

Comment: I said I had an instance of `Class` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html not an instance of appropriate class.

Comment: @Dims. I came across this post when searching for a way to add a dynamically created bean to application context. This solution does work. Is this the best way to do it. Did you come across any other way to implement the same.